# how can I tab scroll items in image gallery in django with javascript

Tags: javascript, django, for-loop, django-models, arraylist

i am trying to do a tab image gallery in django using javascript to activate it dynamically. How to pass the variable to onclick="currentSlide()" to make it work incrementally .

```html
#template -property_info.html

        
<div class="container">

<!-- Full-width images with number text -->
{% for p in images %}
<div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
    <img src="{{p.images_of_property.url}}" style="width:100%">
    <h1>{{p.id}}</h1>
</div>
{% endfor %}



<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

<!-- Image text -->
<div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
</div>

<!-- Thumbnail images -->
this is where i have issues . i dont know how to pass the value so it can increment dynamically.
{% for p in images %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="{{p.images_of_property.url}}" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide('{{p.id}}')" alt="property img">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    
</div>
</div>



#styles
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */
.container {
position: relative;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
display: none;
}

/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */
.cursor {
cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
width: auto;
padding: 16px;
margin-top: -50px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
color: #f2f2f2;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}

/* Container for image text */
.caption-container {
text-align: center;
background-color: #222;
padding: 2px 16px;
color: white;
}

.row:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}

/* Six columns side by side */
.column {
float: left;
width: 16.66%;
}

/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */
.demo {
opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```js
# js       
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    let captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

```py
# views.py

def imageGallery(request,id):
    items = get_object_or_404(Property,id=id)
    images = PropertyImages.objects.filter(property_details=items)
    context={'images':images, 'items':items}

    return render(request,'image_gallery.html',context)
```

Comment: I found a way out. I added forloop.counter to access each item. 
{% for p in images %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" id="{{ forloop.counter }}">
        <img class="demo cursor" src="{{p.images_of_property.url}}" id="{{p.id}}" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide('{{forloop.counter}}')" alt="The Woods">
      </div>
      {% endfor %}